# Приведение строки в численный формат

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var map;
var x= -34.397;
var his = Number("$('td').eq(19).html();");

alert(his);

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat:his, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
};


initMap();
```

Уже всё разобрал. Осталось только приведение поля к числу. Никак не могу разобрать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы ссылаетесь не на содержимое ячейки, а указываете строку  содержащую этот текст: `$('td').eq(19).html()`. Сделайте так `Number($('td').eq(19).html())` или попробуйте такой вариант:

```
var map;
var x= -34.397;
var his = parseFloat($('td').eq(19).html()); // Преобразовывает строку в число

alert(his);

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat:his, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
};

initMap();
```